# Sahi Pro - not able to change date format from "Thursday 02 Mar 2017" to "MM/DD/YYYY"

Tags: javascript, sahi

I am trying to convert date format in the Sahi Pro using the following code but no luck:

**I want to convert "Thursday 02 Mar 2017" into "03/02/2017"**

```
_setValue(_textbox("j_username"), "*******");
_setValue(_password("j_password"), "*******");
_click(_span("Login"));
_click(_span("Home"));

_wait(2000);

var $date = _getText(_div("/date-display .* bwc-selected/"));

_wait(2000);

_log($date);

_wait(2000);

var $date = _getText(_div("/date-display .* bwc-selected/"));
var $old_date_format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(_getText(_div("/date-display .* bwc-selected/"))).parse($date);
var $converted_date_format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format($old_date_format);

_log($converted_date_format);
```

After running above code I am getting following error for formatting fate:

```
Wrapped java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'T' (C:\SahiPro\userdata\scripts\Trial.sah#11)
```

Comment: Why are you calling java here? Just use any JS function to convert your data and use _call or _eval to execute js

Comment: hi Vivek - Finally, I used java script and found the solution. I posted solution in the Answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research on Java script and came up with following solution:

Following code converted "Thursday 02 Mar 2017" into "03/02/2017"

```
var $date = _getText(_div("/date-display .* bwc-selected/"));

_wait(2000);

_log($date);

_wait(2000);

var str = ($date)

var d = new Date(str)

var $systemDate = (d.getUTCMonth()+1) +"/"+ d.getUTCDate() + "/" + d.getUTCFullYear();

_log($systemDate);
```